# How to register custom build Autofac.Module in Orchard?

Tags: dependency-injection, orchardcms, autofac

I have a piece of code that encapsulates functionality that isn't specific to Orchard. However i need to make it available in Orchard via dependency injection. So, I built up an Autofac Module that registers all components (types), but I can't find a way to inform Orchard's Autofac Container about it.

From what i red, there are two ways to add a module to a container:

By supplying the module at to the ContainerBuilder (usually at start-up), 
Or by updating the already built Container at runtime with a ContainerBuilder

I can approach the problem in the first way, but I rather do a variant of the second if there is such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a class deriving from `Autofac.Module` to your Orchard module and that's it. It will get automatically picked by Orchard during the container construction.

Comment: I believe I've done this - I've added to my Orchard module (i.e. to the .csproj) a public class LoaderModule : Autofac.Module which implements protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder) but its code isn't getting invoked at any point. EDIT: resolved - see full answer below.

Comment: @Piotr thanks for you'r answer, could you please clarify how orchard automatically pick modules?cause i couldn't see any thing either like `RegisterAssemblyModules()` nor manual assembly scan.

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili The whole container creation magic happens within `ShellContainerFactory` class. It's more complicated than just calling `RegisterAssemblyModules()` - there is a manual assembly scan, although it's very indirect (via the `ShellBlueprint`).

Comment: @PiotrSzmyd This is not working for me please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70526733/orchardcore-autofac-module-dependency-registration-not-working

Answer (score 1):

[Piotr Szmyd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13771797/1662268) is fundamentally correct, but here's some more detail:

Your Orchard Module is the new .csproj that you've added to the Orchard.sln
Add Autofac as a reference to that csproj (make sure you use the version included with Orchard - not nuget. [See here for more details about that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700524/including-autofac-module-in-custom-module-breaks-orchard))
Then add a class that derives from Autofac.Module and which implements Load(ContainerBuilder).
e.g.

```
using System;
using Autofac;

namespace MyCustom.Module.Namespace
{
  public class LoaderModule : Autofac.Module
  {
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
      builder.RegisterType<MyClass>().As<IMyInterface>();
    }
  }
}
```

As an additional note:
The Autofac registration code only gets invoked at application startup time.
If you are running with the site sitting locally in IIS and the code in VS, then the dynamic compilation nature of Orcahrd means that when you recompile the code, the application doesn't stop.

So in order for this Autofac registration code to be hit (and also for any channges to it to take effect) you have to iisreset to kill the application, so that it reloads the Autofac Registrations.