# Including Autofac.Module in custom module breaks Orchard

Tags: http-status-code-404, orchardcms, autofac

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771734/how-to-register-custom-build-autofac-module-in-orchard) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584085/how-to-access-overall-autofac-container-to-register-a-dependency-in-orchard) for why I'm trying to do this.

I have a custom module that I'm building (and which is it's own .csproj in the Orchard .sln, as normal)

I have a (relatively complex) dependency that I wish to inject into Orchard.
Currently if I build and run the code it's perfectly happy until it hits my dependency at which point it null-refs (as I'd expect it to). I can access the admin site and any pages that don't reference the dependency.

I add a reference to Autofac to my project. -> All fine.

I add the following class:

```
using System;
using Autofac;

namespace MyCustom.Module.Namespace
{
  public class LoaderModule
  {}
}
```

Everything is still fine - I rebuild and still get the expected behaviour.
Then I make my `LoaderModule` derive from `Autofac.Module` as instructed elsewhere:

```
using System;
using Autofac;

namespace MyCustom.Module.Namespace
{
  public class LoaderModule : Autofac.Module
  {}
}
```

And suddenly I'm getting "The resource cannot be found." 404s from IIS for the entire Orchard site - including admin site and content pages which done't hit the dependency.

Help!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah! It was a versioning issue.

Starting the site with debugger attached, and breaking on all exceptions revealed things like this:

`{"Could not load file or assembly 'Autofac, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"Autofac, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da"}`

I'd added Autofac from nuget, but Orchard itself was using a bundled version that was different.
Removing my nuget reference to Autofac and re-adding by locating the bundled copy of Autofac.dll made the problem go away.