# OrchardCore - Autofac module dependency registration not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac, orchardcore

I just added OrchardCore to my project that already had Autofac module and everything was working correctly.
Then I adding:

```
services.AddOrchardCore().AddMvc();
```

And:

```
app.UseOrchardCore();
```

to the Startup.cs.
The autofac registration stopped working and I get this exception:
InvalidOperationException: `Unable to resolve service for type 'Tharwat.DataAccess.IRepositoryAsync 1[Tharwat.Easy.Domain.Models.WifiNetworks.Network]' while attempting to activate 'Tharwat.Easy.Web.Controllers.WifiNetworks.NetworkController'`

This is how I register Autofac Module in the Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModule());
        }

public class AutofacModule: Autofac.Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            //base.Load(builder);

        var asm = new[]
        {
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
            Assembly.Load("Tharwat.Easy.Domain"),
            Assembly.Load("Tharwat.Easy.DataAccess"),
        };

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(asm)
               .AsImplementedInterfaces()
               .PublicOnly();
          ...
          ...
          ...
    }
}
```

I understood that OrchardCore uses Autofac, but why it overrides my autofac regiseration and what should I do to make it work.

Comment: Reading this article may be useful to you:https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/issues/2112